# Android - Custom Listview Scrolling is Very Slow

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, android-custom-view, android-adapter

I've got a listview which sometimes inflate a XML (TextView Item) or another XML (TextView+Image Item). And i followed these instructions to get a better performance.

http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html

https://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-world-of-listview-android.pdf

http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

It's now better, but still can't get best performance and still scroll is working slowly. Here's my code :

GetView :  (//ViewHolder 0 -> Section Item
ViewHolder 1 -> Entry Item)

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder[] viewHolders=new ViewHolder[2];
        final ListItems.Item i = items.get(position);
        if (i != null) {
            if(i.isSection()){
                TextView sectionView;
                ListItems.SectionItem si = (ListItems.SectionItem)i;
                if (v==null || ((ViewHolder[])v.getTag())==null || ((ViewHolder[])v.getTag())[0]==null)
                {
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.order_list_item_section, null);
                    sectionView= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
                    viewHolders[0]=new ViewHolder();
                    viewHolders[0].Title=sectionView;
                    v.setTag(viewHolders);
                }
                else
                {
                    viewHolders[0]=((ViewHolder[]) v.getTag())[0];
                    sectionView=viewHolders[0].Title;
                }
                sectionView.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.BLACK);
                sectionView.setText(si.getTitle());
            }
            else if(i.isEntryItem())
            {               
                ListItems.EntryItem ei = (ListItems.EntryItem)i;
                TextView title = null,subtitle = null;
                ImageView img = null;
                if (v==null || ((ViewHolder[])v.getTag())==null || ((ViewHolder[])v.getTag())[1]==null)
                {
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.order_list_item_entry, null);
                    title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_title);
                    img=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_drawable);
                    subtitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_summary);
                    viewHolders[1]=new ViewHolder();
                    viewHolders[1].Title=title;
                    viewHolders[1].SubTitle=subtitle;
                    viewHolders[1].TableImage=img;
                    v.setTag(viewHolders);
                }
                else
                {
                    viewHolders[1]=((ViewHolder[]) v.getTag())[1];
                    title=viewHolders[1].Title;
                    subtitle=viewHolders[1].SubTitle;
                    img=viewHolders[1].TableImage;
                }
                title.setTextSize(20);
                title.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.BLACK);
                title.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b><i>"+ei.title+"</b></i>"));
                img.setImageBitmap(ei.tableImage);  
                img.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                img.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                if(!ei.subtitle.equals(""))
                {
                    subtitle.setTextSize(15);
                    subtitle.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.GRAY);
                    subtitle.setText(Html.fromHtml("<i>"+ei.subtitle+"</i>"));
                }
            }

ViewHolder : 

    static class ViewHolder {
          TextView Title;
          TextView SubTitle;
          ImageView TableImage;
         }
```

**EDIT :**

order_list_item_section.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/list_item_section_text"
        layout="@android:layout/preference_category" />

</LinearLayout>
```

order_list_item_entry.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_drawable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" /> 

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I need any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: It sometime will be caused by how you define your xml layout, mine to post also those xmls you're inflating? And are you extending ArrayAdapter? when you have this kind of list where you would inflate different kind of layout, consider extending BaseAdapter instead. Which then you could always reuse your convertView instead of inflating each time getView is called

Comment: Posting now.... I posted XML files. Yes i'm using ArrayAdapter, can you show me an axample about BaseAdapter

Comment: I've tried to change it BaseAdapter but result is still same. Maybe really slightly better.

Comment: Not sure if you did it the correct way, when I say extend BaseAdapter I mean you can return 2 at `getViewTypeCount()`, and specific view type at `getItemViewType()`, did you implement this two function correctly? And try this 2 debug: First, remove the ellipsize and fadingedge, and for both TextView set the width to `match_parent`, if scrolling still slow, try, Second, `scaleType="fitXY"` together with `wrap_content` on ImageView actually sounds quite, conflicting if you ask me, try specifically setting the width and height to maybe 48dp or 55dp, then fitXY makes sense, just give both a try.

Comment: I implemented `getViewTypeCount()`  but i don't need `getItemViewType()`. Because i'm already choosing type with `i.isEntryItem()` or `i.isSectionItem()`. Ow I saw it trying..

Comment: IT's completely GOOD NOW! First one WORKED! Thank you so much please write it as answer including baseadapter info too. So i can accept it.

Comment: It's ok lol, just update your question with a solution so that people can see it. As for BaseAdapter I will post as an answer below but do not accept it because its not an answer, will only provide you better performance.

Comment: believe me it's an answer and a good one. Just write so people can see it. :) Thanks again i was struggling with it for days

Comment: In my project overriding the getItemViewType() makes my RecyclerView slow. Trying to find replacement. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is accepted I think I need to include the debug here:

1. Remove the `ellipsize` and `fadingedge`, and for both TextView set the width to `match_parent`, if scrolling still slow, try next.
2. `scaleType="fitXY"` together with `wrap_content` on ImageView actually sounds quite, conflicting if you ask me, try specifically setting the width and height to maybe 48dp or 55dp, then `fitXY` makes sense.

Here's an example of functions to a proper BaseAdapter class:

```
public static final int SECTION = 2;
public static final int ENTRY_ITEM = 1;
private List<ListItems.Item> items; // I believe you have this List declared?

public YourClassConstructor(){
    //Whatever you need to accept and assign, probably the list itself.
}

public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return (long) position; // Or anything that can define your item
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2; // 2 because you have Section and EntryItem
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int itemViewType;
    ListItems.Item i = items.get(position);

    if(i.isSection()){
        itemViewType = SECTION;
    }else{
        itemViewType = ENTRY_ITEM;
    }

    return itemViewType;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent {
    //Here your convertView will always be the one you need, either as a section or entry_item
    //Unless there is no convertView available yet.
    //So your (ViewHolder[])v.getTag())[0/1] will less likely be null.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do `v = vi.inflate(R.layout.order_list_item_section, null);` **only** if v is null. It will help a lot.

Comment: You're right, sorry, not an excuse, but this is why Google suggest to avoid long lines of code like this one `if (v==null || ((ViewHolder[])v.getTag())==null || ((ViewHolder[])v.getTag())[0]==null)` :-)